# Can the word "mither" be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns

Can the word **mither** - a regional word that I have come across more and more recently - be used as a noun?

I understand that it isn't listed as a noun in dictionaries, but my husband uses it as a noun and I am trying to make sure that it grammatical features allow that.

---

Added from comments:

I have looked at 'mithering' which means to bother. The context that it is used in my region is

> 'you'll be in mither if you do not stop what you're doing'.

I have seen the definition for mother and the OED lists a few senses such as the one mentioned. Some are adjectives, transitives etc. The sense that I'm using it in seems to be a noun, does it?

---

@MartinSmith offered this example:

> ### Steven Gerrard trial: what does 'mither' mean?
>
> Steven Gerrard told the court he had suffered "a lot of mither" during his career as a professional footballer, meaning he is frequently bothered by others.

(From [*The Telegraph, 24 July 2009*](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/liverpool/5895227/Steven-Gerrard-trial-what-does-mither-mean.html))

---

OP: The Steven Gerrard example is the same context as I am using it. He is from Liverpool and I'm just down the road in Manchester.

Comment: Since hardly anyone knows what it means I'd say you can use it however you want.

Comment: Hello, amanda. What research have you done? In looking for a delexical usage, 'had a mither' returns only 4 Google hits, and these are for the dialect form of 'mother'.

Comment: Here's one example of it being used as a noun http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/liverpool/5895227/Steven-Gerrard-trial-what-does-mither-mean.html

Comment: I have looked at 'mithering' which means to bother. The context that it is used in my region is 'you'll be in mither if you do not stop what you're doing'. I have seen the definition for mother and the OED lists a few senses such as the one mentioned. Some are adjectives, transitives ect. The sense that I'm using it in seems to be a noun, does it?

Comment: The Steven Gerrard example is the same context as I am using it. He is from Liverpool and I'm just down the road in Manchester. This context does seem to be regional. Thank you

Comment: Yes. It obviously _is_ used, at least in the phrase 'in a mither'. It was never wise to challenge Steven Gerrard. But it's a colloquialism, and reasonably rare. I'd only use it judiciously. Even though 'Stop mithering' was commonplace just up the road in Oldham 50-odd years ago.

Comment: My husband uses the phrase I gave earlier with our children and really emphasises the mither part, it is funny as well as many phrases from where I come from.

Comment: What Edwin said: @Martin - your link specifically refers to the *verb* usage (with 3 different Wikipedia definitions). Which is not to say you *can't* use it as a noun, but it would be *very* unusual. There are no instances of *in a mither* in Google Books, for example.

Comment: So in the phrase I left in the Earlier post 'you'll be in mither if you don't stop' mither being referred to as 'trouble: is it being used as a noun?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Eh? In the phrase "a lot of mither" the word is clearly being used as a noun rather than a verb. E.g as "bother" can be a noun.

Comment: And of course the "e-mither" as coined by Mark and Lard on radio 1...

Comment: @Martin: There are only two written instances of [a lot of mither](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+lot+of+mither%22) in Google Books, and one of *those* is a somewhat creative translation (of Balzac's *Ursule Mirouet*). Essentially it's a rare dialectal *verb*, which even more rarely might get used as a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It seems to be an uncountable noun, so you really wouldn't expect to find *"in a mither"*.  And it's hopeless to search "*in mither*" because almost all hits are a dialectical pronunciation of *"mother"*. You can find [all this mither](https://books.google.com/books?id=tDsjCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&dq=%22all+this+mither%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip6sWU0I3TAhUk4oMKHSiKCHcQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22all%20this%20mither%22&f=false) in Google Books.

Comment: @amanda  My parents are/were from Oldham and brought the word with them to Scotland where they used it regularly. Mostly as verb but also as a noun.

Answer (score 4):

The OED has an entry for the verb *mither* as a variant of *moider*.

The chief meaning of the latter is:

> 1. trans. To confuse, perplex, bewilder; to exhaust, overcome, stupefy; (occas.) to pester (cf. mither v. 2). Chiefly refl. or in
>      pass.

But another important meaning is:

> 3. intr. To be delirious, to babble; to wander about aimlessly, ramble. (cf. mither v. 3). Also fig.

It is reckoned to be of Irish/Manx origin, and the first example the OED gives is from 1587.

The link provided by @Martin Smith is to an article in the Daily Telegraph which quotes Steve Gerrard, at his 2009 trial, saying he had received *a lot of mither* (i.e. using it as a noun) - presumably 'a lot of pester and burden from people'. Since Gerrard is a Skouser it may well be a word widely used and understood in Liverpool, a city with a vast Irish influence.

Comment: My geography isn't the best, is Oldham a North-west region?

Comment: *A regional word that I have come across more and more recently and I was wondering if it can be used as a noun?* In what context would you like to use it - it is not a word that a huge percentage of the English-speaking population would likely know.

Comment: @Cargill It is not a word with which I am intimately familiar; though I have some recollection of having heard it. The OED describes it only as a verb. I am not a northerner though I have in the last fifteen years spent a good deal of time in Manchester, where my daughter was, until recently, living. I have not heard it in Manchester.  My guess is that it is Liverpool argot. Liverpool speech is quite different to Manchester's, and the rest of Lancashire's, with a huge Irish component. And Gerrard is a Skouser to the soles of his very talented feet.

Comment: So if I had the phrase 'you'll be in mither if you don't stop' mither being used as a noun, would stop be a verb and you'll the subject ?

Comment: @Amanda As I explained, the OED does not list it as a noun, only as a verb. But that Telegraph article quoted Steve Gerrard as saying he had received *a lot of mither*. So you decide. You may need to learn some basic rules on parsing. I would strongly recommend you go to the English Language Learners site.

Comment: @Spagirl You should ask that of Edwin Ashworth, a frequent contributor to this site. He is an Oldham man, and will know if anyone does.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Can you help Spagirl? Is the term *mither* much used in the Manchester area, and specifically, Oldham?

Comment: @Spagirl Sorry about that. Btw Manchester has a capital M.

Comment: @WS2 I was apparently a little out of sorts yesterday, for which I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

More as an adjective than as a noun perhaps?

So for example in fairly widespread Irish vernacular of English, you could refer to a mithered person.

I cannot comment on the Manx origin posited above, but can confirm Irish common usage and likely origin. Liverpool as a historic port city, has a huge Irish diaspora, particularly from the middle 1800s, when many of the arriving emigres came from Gaelic speaking districts.

Refs [craicing-the-irish-language-code](http://www.irishtimes.com/news/craicing-the-irish-language-code-1.1096171), 
[hidden-dublin.com/sayings](http://www.hidden-dublin.com/sayings/sayings07.html), 
[Words We Use: The Meaning of Words And Where They Come From By Diarmaid Ó Muirithe](https://books.google.ie/books?id=st34AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT222&lpg=PT222&dq=moithered%20etymology%20irish&source=bl&ots=ZFctigBWVQ&sig=AH9PhfeH8ZmR3bRX2KqAIPWKpMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_jYed1I3TAhUKKcAKHYLYB9YQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=moithered%20etymology%20irish&f=false)